# Validación de nombre UNIQUE entre Unidades del mismo Curso dentro de un proyecto de Laravel Filament

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Estoy descubriendo Laravel Filament. Tengo un proyecto con varios modelos, entre otros: `Course` y `Unit`.

Una `Unit` pertenece a un `Course` y un `Course` puede tener una o más `Unit`.

Dentro del `form` del `CourseResource`, tengo un establecido un `Wizard` para disponer de un formulario Multipasos.
En el primero de los `Step`, establezco los datos del propio *Course* (name, description, ...).
En el último `Step`, es dónde se encuentra un `Repeater` que da la opción de establecer, al mismo tiempo una o varias de todas las *Unit* que pueda contener un *Course*.
Entre los datos que se le puede establecer a una *Unit*, como para un *Course*, está el de *name*.

En el correspondiente `TextInput` de la columna "name" de cada posible *Unit* que se pueda crear dentro del *Course* que se está creando o editando quiero establecer una validación de `unique` de tal manera que el nombre de la unidad sea único pero no entre todas las unidades registradas, sino entre las registradas de un mismo curso.

Esta forma es la manera simple de establecer el UNIQUE para validar el valor con respecto a toda la tabla (sin considerar el curso en cuestión al que pertenece la unidad):

```
    TextInput::make('name')
        ->unique(Unit::class, 'name', ignoreRecord: true)
```

Con esta otra implementación, me funciona bien la validación para que el NAME de la Unit tratada sea UNIQUE entre las unidades del mismo curso. Pero solo funciona en el contexto de la Edición del registro pero no en el contexto de la Creación ya que el `$record` pasado (que se refiere a la unidad que se está editando), aún, no existe:

```
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Unique;

    TextInput::make('name')
        ->unique(Unit::class, 'name', ignoreRecord: true, modifyRuleUsing: function (Unique $rule, string $context, ?Model $record) {
            return $rule
                ->where('course_id', $record->course_id)
        })
```

Entonces, ¿de qué manera establecer el UNIQUE para que verifique que no existe ya un NAME de Unit entre las unidades del mismo curso, tanto al crear el curso y sus unidades como al editar?